# SQL Alchemy python DELETE records, strange schema

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, syntax-error, sql-delete

I have problem with clearing the table (deleting records).

The table have rep schema like that: PROD\USER.TableName

My code looks like that:

```
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={SQL 
SERVER};SERVER=XXXXX;DATABASE=DBNAME;")
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % 
params)

c=engine.connect()
sql=("DELETE * FROM PROD\\USER.TableName")
result=c.execute(sql)
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I makes this work (I cannot change the schema of DB).

```
ERROR: Incorrect syntax near *
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`delete` doesn't take a column list (unless you're using `top`). Just lose the `*`. Additionally, it's probably a good idea to escape the schema name:

```
sql=("DELETE FROM [PROD\\USER].TableName")
```

Comment: Hi Mureinik and Ilja. After the comment of Mureinik worked like a charm but Ilja that was also not bad idea to escape the schema name. 

The only thing I regret is coming here so late, I wasted to much time for such silly problem.

Thank to both of you.